# How to get Work Info Notes and Work Info Summary data in BMC Remedy SOAP service?

Tags: soap, remedy

I am using **HPD_IncidentInterface_WS** WSDL service (Incident Management). This service provides method **HelpDesk_Query_Service**, incident number as a parameter, to get remedy ticket details. However this method doesn't return any information on Work Info Notes and Work Info Summary. How do I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new web-service on the work info form.  You can expose all of the fields there.  You'll need to be sure and expose the incident number field as an input.  Otherwise you won't be able to control which work info records it returns.

Best of luck,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

In the **HPD_IncidentInterface**

there is a method **[HelpDesk_GetWorkInfoList](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/servicedesk81/helpdesk_getworkinfolist-function-228753962.html)** which can be used to obtain the work infos

```
   <urn:HelpDesk_GetWorkInfoList>
     <urn:Qualification>'Incident Number'="INC000000XXXXX"</urn:Qualification>
     <urn:startRecord>0</urn:startRecord>
     <urn:maxLimit>0</urn:maxLimit>
  </urn:HelpDesk_GetWorkInfoList>
```

It returns a list of Work Infos:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns0:HelpDesk_GetWorkInfoListResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_WS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <ns0:ListWOQuery>
        <ns0:getListValues>
           <ns0:WorkInfoInstanceID>ID</ns0:WorkInfoInstanceID>
           <ns0:WorkInfoStatus>Enabled</ns0:WorkInfoStatus>
           <ns0:WorkInfoType>General Information</ns0:WorkInfoType>
           <ns0:WorkInfoCommSource xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoSummary>Summary</ns0:WorkInfoSummary>
           <ns0:WorkInfoNotes>Note</ns0:WorkInfoNotes>
           <ns0:ParentID>INC000000XXXXX</ns0:ParentID>
           <ns0:WorkInfoSecureLog>No</ns0:WorkInfoSecureLog>
           <ns0:WorkInfoSubmitDate>2023-01-16T17:11:25+01:00</ns0:WorkInfoSubmitDate>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment1Name/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment1Data/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment1OrigSize/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment2Name/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment2Data/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment2OrigSize/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment3Name/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment3Data/>
           <ns0:WorkInfoAttachment3OrigSize/>
        </ns0:getListValues>
        </ns0:ListWOQuery>
     </ns0:HelpDesk_GetWorkInfoListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```